# Routing in Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I'm trying to do some routing in Zend Framework 2, but it's not working.

The basics of the skeleton application are working, so I added a new module called User and the following code in the file \module\User\config\module.config.php

```
'controllers' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'User\Controller\User' => 'User\Controller\UserController',
    ),
),

'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(

        'login' => array(
            'type'    => 'Literal',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/login',
                'defaults' => array(
                    '__NAMESPACE__' => 'User\Controller',
                    'controller'    => 'User',
                    'action'        => 'login',
                ),
            ),
        ),

        'user_create' => array(
            'type'    => 'Literal',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/user/create',
                'defaults' => array(
                    '__NAMESPACE__' => 'User\Controller',
                    'controller'    => 'User',
                    'action'        => 'create',
                ),
            ),
        ),

    ),
),
```

If I try to access the first route (/login), it works.

But the second route (/user/create) results in the error:

**File:**

```
F:\www\ZendVendas\library\Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\TreeRouteStack.php:313
```

**Message:**

```
Route with name "create" not found
```

If I do create a route without the controller name, it works:

```
        'create' => array(
            'type'    => 'Literal',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/create',
                'defaults' => array(
                    '__NAMESPACE__' => 'User\Controller',
                    'controller'    => 'User',
                    'action'        => 'create',
                ),
            ),
        ),
```

But I would want the route were "/user/create", and don't "/create".

I have searched for many topics, but can't see where is my mistake.
Appreciate any help ;)

**Edit: ajusted code with suggestions of @Jurian**

```
'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(

        'user' => array(
            'type'    => 'Literal',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/user',
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'User\Controller\User',
                    'action'     => 'profile',
                ),
            ),


            'child_routes' => array(
                'login'  => array(
                    'type' => 'Literal',
                    'options' => array(
                        'route'    => '/login',
                        'defaults' => array(
                            'controller' => 'User\Controller\User',
                            'action'     => 'login',
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
                'create' => array(
                    'type' => 'Literal',
                    'options' => array(
                        'route'    => '/create',
                        'defaults' => array(
                            'controller' => 'User\Controller\User',
                            'action'     => 'create',
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),

    ),
),
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have to understand how routing works in Zend Framework 2. Routes have a name and some configuration. The structure looks as follows:

```
'router' => array(
  'routes' => array(
    'route_name_1' => array( /* config here */ ),
    'route_name_2' => array( /* config here */ ),
    'route_name_3' => array( /* config here */ ),
  ),
),
```

Here the route names are `route_name_1` etc. If you assemble an url, you use *that route name*. So if `route_name_1` has the url `/foo/bar/baz`, you can ask for the url of `route_name_1` by using the url view helper:

```
echo $this->url('route_name_1'); // prints /foo/bar/baz
```

Your url `/user/create` is mapped to the route *name* `user_create` so to assemble this url, you need to pass on the route name:

```
echo $this->url('user_create'); // prints /user/create
```

**CHILD ROUTES**

There is also a concept of child routes. This can give you a route `user` which maps to `/user` and then this user route has a child `create` which maps to `/create` and as such the "total" route of create is `/user/create`. This can be configured as follows:

```
'router' => array(
  'routes' => array(
    'route_name_1' => array( /* config here */ ),
    'route_name_2' => array(
      /* config here */

      'child_routes' => array(
        'child_name_1' => array( /* config here */ ),
        'child_name_2' => array( /* config here */ ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```

Now, if you want to assemble an url for `route_name_2` it just looks as above:

```
echo $this->url('route_name_1');
```

But if you need to assemble the url for `child_name_1` you construct a "path" with a `/` between the name and its parent(s):

```
echo $this->url('route_name_1/child_name_1');
```

So although you can access the `/user/create` route fine with the route name you already have, you might want to use child routes as this gives you a more flexible routing system:

```
'router' => array(
  'routes' => array(
    'user' => array(
      'type'    => 'Literal',
      'options' => array(
        'route'    => '/user/create',
          'defaults' => array(
            'controller' => 'User\Controller\User',
            'action'     => 'profile',
          ),
        ),
      ),

      'child_routes' => array(
        'login'  => array(
          'type' => 'Literal',
          'options' => array(
            'route'    => '/login',
            'defaults' => array(
              'action'     => 'login',
            ),
          ),
        ),
        'create' => array(
          'type' => 'Literal',
          'options' => array(
            'route'    => '/create',
            'defaults' => array(
              'action'     => 'create',
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```

Then you have a route `user` which maps to a "profile". If you assemble `user/create` you go to `/user/create` and it uses the "createAction" from the user controller. The same hapens with `user/login` route.

Comment: Hi @Jurian! Thanks for the detailed explanation. Now I can understand better the structure of the routes. But, unfortunately, it still doesn't work! The error is the same. Maybe am I missing some configuration file? Thanks for you help!

Comment: Can you post then your *updated* route config and the location where you "try to access the route"?

Comment: I have edited the post with the last version of my routing. Now, I try to access the routes (/user/create) and (/user/login), but now the error occurs to both routes

Comment: Hi @Jurian! I managed to find the error. I'll do some more tests and put the answer later. Anyway, thank you very much for your help! Regards

Answer (score 0):

I have found what I was doing wrong.

In one of my view files, there was a URL function pointing to the route `/create`.
It would be much helpful if Zend indicated the file with the invalid route, but, once I found the mistake, everything is working now.

```
'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(

        'login' => array(
            'type'    => 'Literal',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/login',
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'User\Controller\User',
                    'action'     => 'login',
                ),
            ),
        ),

        'logout' => array(
            'type'    => 'Literal',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/logout',
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'User\Controller\User',
                    'action'     => 'logout',
                ),
            ),
        ),

        'user' => array(
            'type'    => 'Literal',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/user',
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'User\Controller\User',
                    'action'     => 'profile',
                ),
            ),
            'child_routes' => array(
                'create' => array(
                    'type' => 'Literal',
                    'options' => array(
                        'route'    => '/create',
                        'defaults' => array(
                            'controller' => 'User\Controller\User',
                            'action'     => 'create',
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
                'edit' => array(
                    'type' => 'Literal',
                    'options' => array(
                        'route'    => '/edit',
                        'defaults' => array(
                            'controller' => 'User\Controller\User',
                            'action'     => 'edit',
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),      

    ),
),
```

Thank you for the help!

Comment: How would ZF2 know the "wrong route" if it doesn't find a route? ^^

Comment: I mean ZF2 could point the *file* that has an invalid route. Like this: `File: \module\User\view\user\user\create.phtml` `Message: Route with name "create" not found` :)

Comment: What a shame... Now I saw it. LOL! Thank you Sam! =D