# How to remove controller name and action name from url in zend framework2

Tags: zend-framework2

My url appears to be :

http://test.scampaigns.com/New/index/qwertyui/287

which I want to be :

http://test.scampaigns.com/qwertyui/287

How is this possible?

router.config.php added......

```
'new' => array(

    'type' => 'segment',
                'options' => array(
                    'route' => '/[/:id][/:pId]',
                    'constraints' => array(
                        'id' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                        'pId' => '[0-9]+',
                    ),
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'Application\Controller\New',
                        'action' => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
```

controllers.config.php

```
'controllers' => array(

    'invokables' => array(
            'Application\Controller\New' => 'Application\Controller\NewController'
        ),
    ),
```

Comment: Can I see your router.config.php?

Comment: I am actually ignorant of what to write in router.config.php for the above.....

Comment: Can you try using 'route' => '/:id/:pId',

Answer (score 0):

I really did a few projects in Zend, but as I recall, it would be something about routes.

Check this question and answer of StackOverflow, there's a well explanation there and might as well guide you.

[Routing in Zend Framework 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19150934/routing-in-zend-framework-2)